# Vertical order traversal of binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal

I am trying to perform Vertical order traversal of binary tree as follows:
    1) Finding out the minimum and maximum horizontal distance of each nodes from the root node
    2) Creating a hashmap that maps horizontal distances to corresponding nodes(Map>)

However i am getting undesired output and i think there is something wrong in the implementation as the algorithm seems correct to me.

Here is the complete code:

```
 import java.util.*;

class Node{
    int data;
    Node right;
    Node left;
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Min_Max{
    int min;
    int max;
    Min_Max(int min, int max){
        this.min=min;
        this.max=max;
    }
}

class VerticalOrderTraversalUsingHashing{

    public static void findMinMax(Node root,Min_Max obj, int hd){

        if(root==null)
            return;

        if(hd > obj.max)
            obj.max = hd;
        else if(hd < obj.min)
            obj.min = hd;

        findMinMax(root.left, obj, hd-1);
        findMinMax(root.right, obj, hd+1);
    }

    public static void verticalOrderTraversal(Node root, Map<Integer,Vector<Integer>> map,int hd){

        if(root == null)
            return;
        if(map.get(hd)==null){
            Vector<Integer> temp = new Vector<>();
            temp.add(root.data);
            map.put(hd,temp);
        } else {
            Vector<Integer> temp = map.get(hd);            
            temp.add(root.data);
            map.put(hd,temp);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Node root = new Node(12);
        root.left = new Node(6);
        root.right = new Node(19);
        root.left.right = new Node(8);
        root.left.left = new Node(-23);
        root.right.left = new Node(18);
        root.right.right = new Node(52);

        Min_Max obj = new Min_Max(99999, -99999);
        findMinMax(root, obj, 0);

        Map<Integer,Vector<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for(int  i=obj.min;i<=obj.max;i++){
            Vector <Integer> v = new Vector<>();
            v.add(99999);//dummy node to initialize the map
            map.put(i,v);
        }

        verticalOrderTraversal(root, map, 0);

        Set keys = map.keySet();
        Iterator itr=keys.iterator();

        System.out.println(map); 
    }
}
```

Output : {-1=[99999], 0=[99999, 12], -2=[99999], 1=[99999], 2=[99999]}
So what is wrong with my approcah?

Comment: What is horizontal distance as you understand it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Its basically the distance of the node from the root node...the left children would have negative horizontal distance taking the root at zeroth level and the right children would have positive horizontal distance.

Comment: Does a min hd make sense here? *root* node whose hd is 0 is obvious the min one.

Comment: @Xlee Nope..root isn't the minimum..
For instance, if the root has a left child....its horizontal distance from the root node would be -1..similarly if the root child's left child has a left and right child..then their horizontal distances would be -2 and 0 respectively...
Hence the leftmost child will have the minimum horizontal distance..

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bfs and add `-1` on left and `+1` on right.
You can then keep adding the result in a TreeMap and then add all the values in the result.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> verticalOrder(TreeNode root) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(root == null) { return result; }
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        helper(root, map);
        result.addAll(map.values());
        return result;
    }
    
    private void helper(TreeNode root, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map) {
        Queue<TreeNode> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<>();
        
        q1.offer(root);
        q2.offer(0);
        
        while(!q1.isEmpty()) {
            TreeNode curr = q1.poll();
            int order = q2.poll();
            
            List<Integer> list = map.getOrDefault(order, new ArrayList<>());
            list.add(curr.val);
            map.put(order, list);
            
            if(curr.left != null) {
                q1.offer(curr.left);
                q2.offer(order - 1);
            }
            
            if(curr.right != null) {
                q1.offer(curr.right);
                q2.offer(order + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```